# Whenever I run my OpenGL Code I get a white screen and a crash

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

Whenever I run my code for OpenGL, the window that I create will pop-up for a few seconds as a blank, white, window and then immediately crashed. I get the error code: (process 15692) exited with code -1073741819.

I'm not sure what the problem is. I used some classes that I made such as, Shader which just creates a program given two shaders. Here is the code below:

```
#pragma once

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>


#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#ifndef STBI_INCLUDE_STB_IMAGE_H
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"
#endif
#include "Shader.h"

void processInput(GLFWwindow* window, Shader Program) {
    static glm::mat4 BasicMatrix;
    static glm::vec3 BasicVector;

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS) {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
    }
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS) {
        BasicMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        BasicMatrix = translate(BasicMatrix, glm::vec3(0.05f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(Program.ID, "Matrices"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(BasicMatrix));
    }
}

void runTest() {
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        throw(-1);
        std::cout << "Error: GLFW Init Failed" << std::endl;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1920, 1080, "HAHAH BRRR", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW Window \n";
        glfwTerminate();
        throw (-1);
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = true;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        std::cout << "GLEW INIT FAILED\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    //The first two parameters set the position of the lower left corner
    glViewport(0, 0, 1920, 1080);


    float vertex[] = {

        -0.15f, -0.15f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.15f, 0.15f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.15f, 0.15f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.15f, 0.15f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f

    };

    unsigned int vertices[] = {
        0, 1, 3,
        3, 1, 2
    };

    const char* vertexTexShader =
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "\n"
        "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
        "layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;\n"
        "layout (location = 2) in vec2 TexCoords;\n"
        "\n"
        "out vec3 Color;\n"
        "out vec2 TexCoord;\n"
        "\n"
        "uniform mat4 Matrices;\n"
        "\n"
        "void main(){\n"
        "\n"
        "gl_Position = Matrices * vec4(aPos, 1.0f);\n"
        "Color = aColor;\n"
        "TexCoord = TexCoords;\n"
        "\n"
        "}\n";

    const char* fragmentTexShader =
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "\n"
        "in vec3 Color;\n"
        "in vec2 TexCoord;\n"
        "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
        "uniform sampler2D texture1;\n"
        "\n"
        "void main(){\n"
        "\n"
        "\n"
        "FragColor = texture(texture1, TexCoord) * Color;\n"
        "\n"
        "\n"
        "}\n";

    Shader GameProgram(vertexTexShader, fragmentTexShader, 1);

    unsigned int VAO4, VBO4, EBO4;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO4);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO4);

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO4);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO4);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertex), vertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, &EBO4);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO4);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);


    unsigned int Texture3;
    glGenTextures(1, &Texture3);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture3);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    int width, heigth, nrChannles;
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load("src/Images/awesomeface.png", &width, &heigth, &nrChannles, 4);
    if (data) {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGB, width, heigth, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Could Not Generate Texture\n REASON:";
        std::cout << stbi_failure_reason();
    }

    GameProgram.use();
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(GameProgram.ID, "texture1"), 0);

    while (glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        processInput(window, GameProgram);

        glClearColor(0.5f, 0.2f, 0.6f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture3);



        glBindVertexArray(VAO4);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }


    glfwTerminate();
}
```

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: My debugger says: Exception thrown at 0x7989DE78 (ig75icd32.dll) in RandomOpenGL.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x01170000.

Comment: If you run a *debug* build in your debugger, where in *your* code does the crash happen? What are the values of all involved variables at that point?

Comment: By the way, are you showing is a *source* file or a *header* file? If it's a source file you should not use the `#pragma once`, and if it's a header file you should not define (implement) functions in it.

Comment: It's a header file. Sorry, I'm new to the debugger on VS.

Comment: `0xC0000005: Access violation` means you are accessing memory that is not yours (some compilers throw Segmentation fault instead) ... usual cause is using uninitialized or NULL pointer, `location 0x01170000` is the process local address that causes this in case of NULL pointer its usually offset of structure you accessed... debuger wil lshow you exact line of code where this happens ...

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Comment: Yeah, the issue is solved, I was passing the memory address of data to glTexImage2D() instead of the data itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the errors in your application can be easily found while debugging your program. Hence I voted to close your question.

Anyway here is a brief list of your mistakes:

- The shader program fails to compile, because the type of the variable `Color` is `vec3`:

  <s>`"FragColor = texture(texture1, TexCoord) * Color;`</s>

  ```c
  FragColor = texture(texture1, TexCoord) * vec4(Color, 1.0);
  ```
- Furthermore there is a typo:

  <s>`glGenBuffers(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, &EBO4);`</s>

  ```cpp
  glGenBuffers(1, &EBO4);
  ```
- The 2nd argument of [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) must be 0:

  <s>`glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGB, width, heigth, 0, GL_RGBA,  GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &data);`</s>

  ```cpp
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, heigth, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &data);
  ```
- Your application loop terminates immediately:

  <s>`while (glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {`</s>

  ```cpp
  while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
  ```